# $uibModal access dom elemets of template passed in

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We're moving from using angular modal to uibmodal for creating our modals. Previously we accessed our form elements for the template passed in using link

```
    ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: templateUrl,
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: controllerAs,
        inputs: {apiMethod: apiMethod, callback: callback, params : params},
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.dismiss = function() {
                element.modal('hide');
            };
        }
```

This isn't an option with uibmodal without creating a new directive. Is there an easy way to access the DOM at this point? We'd like to take the elements in the DOM (text inputs) and pass them to our chosen apimethod.

```
$uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: templateUrl,
                controller: controller,
                controllerAs: controllerAs,
                resolve: {params: function(){return params;},apiMethod: function(){return apiMethod;}}
            });
```

This is what the controller did previously - the issue is that we no longer have access to the element(s):

Controller:

```
$scope.params = params;
        $scope.close = function (result,form) {
            if (result == 'Save') {
                var uri = apiMethod + "?accountId=" + $routeParams.accountId;
                $http.post(uri, formToKeyValueListJSON($element))
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $uibModalInstance.close({status:'Success', data: data}, 500); // close, but give 500ms for bootstrap to animate
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $uibModalInstance.close({status:'Fail', data: data},500);
                    });
            }
        };
```

Comment: Why do you need DOM access? Why not just bind the inputs to a model in your controller, and pass them to your API that way?

Comment: As the inputs will be dynamic I'm not sure this would work. For instance we might want to provide many modal templates to this handler, take their inputs and send them to an api to process

Comment: It seems like this blog covers one possible solution (and using link in the directive), but it would be nice to know if there was a way to do it without creating a new directive http://blog.vizuri.com/create-dynamic-modal-directive-minutes